# Microsoft teams payload in a for loop

Tags: python, list, microsoft-teams

I have a list of items I want to be iterated over and included in a payload to be sent to teams but only the first items in the list get posted.

```py
items = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]

for item in items:
    payload = {
      "@type": "MessageCard",
      "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
      "themeColor": "FFFFFF",
      "summary": "a short description of things",
      "text": str(item)
    }
```

At the moment only `first` gets posted and in a single message card. Is there a way to list all items in a single card?

Comment: What do you want the end result to look like? Do you want 4 different payloads or do  you want `"text"` to map to a comma delimited string?

Comment: Sorry I am just seeing this. I need just one payload. In a single message card.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want 4 separate payloads to send, you'll need to make an array:

```
items = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]
payloads = []
for item in items:
    payload = {
      "@type": "MessageCard",
      "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
      "themeColor": "FFFFFF",
      "summary": "a short description of things",
      "text": str(item)
    }
    payloads.append(payload)
```

In case you want a payload with all the items separated by some character or string (comma here):

```
items = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]
payload = {
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
    "themeColor": "FFFFFF",
    "summary": "a short description of things",
    "text": ','.join(items)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Trying it out. But should the last text in the payload to be joined be `item` or `items`?

Comment: Whoops, fixed it. There should be no loop in the second version.

Comment: Thanks. But assuming that there are commas in the strings in the list, would your approach still work?

Comment: If there are commas you have to choose a different separator. I don't know how Teams payloads work, I don't know what needs to go into the `text` field. I just answered with two different approaches of what it is you might be trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
payload = {
      "@type": "MessageCard",
      "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
      "themeColor": "FFFFFF",
      "summary": "a short description of things",
      "text": str(items)
    }
```

Hope I could help!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But you literrally just threw in the list whereas I wanted the items iterated over.